# составление regexp php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

как можно при помощи регулярного выражения заменить `//такой текст//` на `<em>такой текст</em>`? при этом если вдруг попадется ссылка,а мы знаем что в ней есть http:**//** то эти 2 слеша мы не трогаем, спасибо

Comment: Предположительно уже было https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/702728/186083

Comment: А еще есть протоколы `https://`, `ftp://`, `tg://`, `whatsapp://` и много других.

Comment: @Visman нет не было, я умею пользоваться поиском, да и тот ответ мне не подходит как я смотрю

Comment: Ссылка прямо указывает на дубликат, который закрыли. В чем у вас проблема с составление регулярного выражения? И где оно вообще? Сейчас тут только задача поставлена.

Comment: @Владимир уточните, пожалуйста - нужно, что бы ссылки вида http:// и т.п. внутри конструкции `//...//` так же отображались курсивом?

Comment: @Эдуард  дело в том что я составил немного неправильно выражение, и такой текст:  http://test.ru //qwerty// превращался в такой: http:<em>test.ru</em> qwerty// по этому нужно чтобы регулярное выражение не ловило ссылки, а если они находятся внутри то да, их тоже в курсив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на результат этого примера:

```
<?php

$string = 'httр://testtest //
Заменяемый текст и ссылка внутри bb-кода httр://test.ru 
Ещё заменяемый текст. // httр://testtest httр://test.ru test';

$pattern = ["~
    (?!://)
        (?:(\s)|^)
            //(?:\r\n)?(.+?)(?:\r\n)?//
        (?:(\s)|$)
    (?<!://)~xs",
    "~(?!://)//(?:\r\n)?(.+?)(?:\r\n)?//(?<!://)~s"
];

$replace = ['$1<em>$2</em>$3', '<em>$1</em>'];

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64136/discussion-on-answer-by---regexp-php).